# Identify compatible VMWare Player version based on vmx file

Tags: vmware-player

Is it possible to identify which VMWare Player versions can open VM images?  I pasted the vmx file below.

I have this version of VMWare Player: 4.0.6 build-1035888

I'm getting these error messages:

[image]

[image]

Here is my vmx file:

```
.encoding = "windows-1252"
config.version = "8"
virtualHW.version = "9"
scsi0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0.virtualDev = "lsilogic"
memsize = "2048"
scsi0:0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0:0.fileName = "i2b2.vmdk"
ide1:0.present = "TRUE"
ide1:0.fileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Player\linux.iso"
ide1:0.deviceType = "cdrom-image"
floppy0.startConnected = "FALSE"
floppy0.fileName = ""
floppy0.autodetect = "TRUE"
ethernet0.present = "TRUE"
ethernet0.connectionType = "nat"
ethernet0.wakeOnPcktRcv = "FALSE"
ethernet0.addressType = "generated"
usb.present = "TRUE"
ehci.present = "TRUE"
ehci.pciSlotNumber = "35"
sound.present = "TRUE"
sound.fileName = "-1"
sound.autodetect = "TRUE"
serial0.present = "TRUE"
serial0.fileType = "thinprint"
pciBridge0.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge4.functions = "8"
pciBridge5.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge5.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge5.functions = "8"
pciBridge6.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge6.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge6.functions = "8"
pciBridge7.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge7.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge7.functions = "8"
vmci0.present = "TRUE"
hpet0.present = "TRUE"
usb.vbluetooth.startConnected = "TRUE"
displayName = "i2b2"
guestOS = "centos"
nvram = "i2b2.nvram"
virtualHW.productCompatibility = "hosted"
gui.exitOnCLIHLT = "FALSE"
powerType.powerOff = "hard"
powerType.powerOn = "hard"
powerType.suspend = "hard"
powerType.reset = "hard"
extendedConfigFile = "i2b2.vmxf"
scsi0.pciSlotNumber = "16"
ide1:0.startConnected = "FALSE"
ethernet0.generatedAddress = "00:0c:29:eb:d2:48"
ethernet0.pciSlotNumber = "33"
usb.pciSlotNumber = "32"
sound.pciSlotNumber = "34"
vmci0.id = "-1646353000"
vmci0.pciSlotNumber = "36"
tools.syncTime = "FALSE"
uuid.location = "56 4d 63 16 f4 43 80 9e-aa cd 9b c3 1c eb d2 48"
uuid.bios = "56 4d 63 16 f4 43 80 9e-aa cd 9b c3 1c eb d2 48"
cleanShutdown = "TRUE"
replay.supported = "FALSE"
replay.filename = ""
scsi0:0.redo = ""
pciBridge0.pciSlotNumber = "17"
pciBridge4.pciSlotNumber = "21"
pciBridge5.pciSlotNumber = "22"
pciBridge6.pciSlotNumber = "23"
pciBridge7.pciSlotNumber = "24"
usb:1.present = "TRUE"
ethernet0.generatedAddressOffset = "0"
tools.remindInstall = "FALSE"
vmotion.checkpointFBSize = "33554432"
softPowerOff = "TRUE"
usb:1.speed = "2"
usb:1.deviceType = "hub"
usb:1.port = "1"
usb:1.parent = "-1"
usb:0.present = "TRUE"
usb:0.deviceType = "hid"
usb:0.port = "0"
usb:0.parent = "-1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: `config.version = "8"` and `virtualHW.version = "9"` in your config.  That is the important bit. You can then see this table on the Vmware knowledge base.

- http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003746